# Creating custom formula on table columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

My app. is in C# 2008 and back-end is SQL Server. A table in my database has following columns:

**TotalAmount**

**Discount**

**SpecialDiscount**

**Tax**

**NetAmount**

I want my app. to be customizable by the user. A user can create a formula from the above columns to calculate *NetAmount* according to his need.

For example: One user may use simply:

(TotalAmount - Discount - SpecialDiscount) + Tax

But other users might use Tax/2 or Tax * 3.5

How to work with such scenario? Where to store the custom formula and how to substitute values at run-time?

Comment: is this a win forms app or an asp.net/mvc application?

Comment: Why did you tag it with mysql, sql server, and oracle? Do you need a database agnostic solution? Do you have a multi-platform requirement?

Comment: It is a Windows app. I used other tags to enable users of other RDBMS to suggest solution to this database independent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've solved this in two ways: Firs was to allow users to define formulas that are stored in the database in a single table, Formula with Columns:
UserName - as each user can define the formulas
FormulaHeading - to show in the GUI
FormulaText - SQL expression
TableName the name of the table to which the forumla is applied

in code, Select FormulaHeading, FormulaText from Formula and add each formula text as a field to the selection SQL. So your code will look something like this:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT TotalAmount, Discount, SpecialDiscount, Tax, NetAmount {0} From SomeTable", GetUserFormula(userName, tableName));

private string GetUserFormula(string userName, string tableName)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select FormulaText, FormulaHeading FROM Formula WHERE UserName = @userName AND TableName =@TableName"))
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", userName);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("tableName", tableName);
                SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader == null)
                    return result.ToString();
                while (reader.NextResult())
                {
                    result.AppendFormat(", ({0}) AS [{1}]", reader["FormulaText"], reader["FormulaHeading"]);
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

If your GUI is databound you should get a few new correctly named columns with the data worked out by SQL server.

The other approach I've used is to allow the user to define formulas and wrap them in a view within SQL server. The logic is similar but the view is stoerd on the server and you will need to create Instead of triggers on the view for each user with formula.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I'll try and reach you soon.

Comment: What you are assuming in FormulaText and what is FormulaHeading? Secondly, suppose my formula is: (a + b) * c/23, how your query is picking values of columns a, b and c and putting them back in the formula for calculation.

Comment: Formula heading is just the text that you would stick into the column heading in a grid. FormulaText is an SQL expression so if column a was TotalAmount, column b was Discount and columns c was SpecialDiscount, your formula above would read (TotalAmount + Discount) * (SpecialDiscount/23). If the formula header for this was "RPK Discount", your SQL statement generated by the GetUserFormula method would end up being:

Comment: "SELECT TotalAmount, Discount, SpecialDiscount, Tax, NetAmount, (TotalAmount + Discount) * (SpecialDiscount/23) AS [RPK Discount]  From SomeTable"

Answer (score 1):

re: *Where to store the custom formula and how to substitute values at run-time?*

I agree with the answers so far, in that the formula must be stored externally to the source code, in a database table or even a text file.

To substitute the values at run-time, you have a couple of options.

- Store the literal sql syntax
- Store a tokenized version of the sql

You also need to decide what to do with the operations.  If you store the literal sql you can execute directly, you're good, but your end users have to learn sql syntax.

If you want to code a builder for them, you can have each operation in a row of a child table to the table with their userID.

Parent table has columns

```
userID
formulaID
formulaName
```

Child table has columns

```
userID
formulaID
operationSequence
field
operator
value
```

for your example,

```
(TotalAmount - Discount - SpecialDiscount) + Tax / 2
```

the rows in the child table would break down the calculation one arithmetic operation at a time:

```
userID  formulaID  operationSequence  field     operator  value
1       1          1                  tax       /         2
1       1          2                  netamount +         totalAmount
1       1          3                  netamount -         discount
1       1          4                  netamount -         specialDiscount
```

your code knows to store the results of each operation in the netamount field.

If there's only a few things that vary with custom operations, such as the multiplier on the tax field, you could also just store that (1, 0.5, or 3.5 in your examples)

Comment: Both solutions are fantastic. I wonder I don't have any option to distribute the points and can select only one answer. This is the limitation of SO.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar thing going on with regularly used search criteria.

The easiest way, if you have access, is to store the formulas into their own DB Table, they can then be selected by the user, displayed to give the user the option of which to use.